# BigTable Java API vs BigTable HBase Java API differences

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I've developed a HBase application which now I need to port to cloud-big-table. Can I use the easy way out of using BigTable Hbase API or should I redo the code to use BigTable API, given reliable high throughput is a prime requirement ? Or what are the more tangible differences between the two APIs in terms of reliability and performance which can help me decide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both APIs will give you the performance and reliability you're looking for. 
Since you're an existing HBase user, I'd recommend using the HBase client so you can get started on Bigtable right away with a lift-and-shift.

The Bigtable Java API was created to provide a consistent experience with other Google Cloud products such as Spanner, Firestore, etc, so if you were using other GCP products, then it's easy to learn the Bigtable Java API since it follows a familiar structure.

To summarize, each API is designed in a way to make it easy for certain users to get onto Bigtable with an interface they are comfortable with and shouldn't have an effect on the performance, throughput, or reliability.

Comment: Thanks Billy. I guess that's the answer I've been looking for.

Comment: Further if you don't mind billy, we had to move from Synchronous client to Async client due to the throughput issue when we ran our dry runs against Bigtable (it was horrible). Since we moved to Async client we see things are smooth and Bigtable CPU doesn't even notice our initial test loads. But the issue was after the dry run peaking about writing 3000+ rows/s and reading 2500+ rows/s, we noticed randomly some rows were missing, something which our application can never tolerate.

Comment: We are running the test again today with a 2CPU configuration for our GKE deploymend as mentioned here https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable. One way would be to have a callback to check if all the rows were written after async operation, for which I can't seem to find a way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks